# Custom theme for Orchard CMS?

Tags: themes, orchardcms

What I should do except writing owner Site.css? It is possible to give writing Site.css to designer without any worry about merger functionallity and design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. In some cases, CSS is enough. In some cases, not, and you also need to change layout and a number of other templates. CSS should be no problem for your designer. For templates, they just have to understand what the @{}, @() and @ are doing and learn not to touch these parts and work around them. Good web designers should be used to that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an [intro blog post on theming Orchard](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/theming-orchard).

On my latest project the designer in our team read it so he could turn his designs into an Orchard Template.

The key thing we found was that the designer needed to have his own local version of Orchard running that he could make changes to and see the affects. We had him running it through Visual Studio, but Web Matrix or IIS running locally with him using his own editor of choice would have been just as good.

A combination of the Developer module and visual studio helped him work out what was what.

My article is not pitched at designers though, so I did pair him with a developer at first to get him started. This worked really well and the designer now feels confident and can make new templates from scratch by himself.